# How to resolve @angular dependencies when using ExpressJS and Angular2?

Tags: express, angular, systemjs, zonejs

I'm trying to write a web application with ExpressJS and Angular2. Zone.js appears to be trying (unsuccessfully) to load some @angular libraries, but I'm not sure how to approach fixing it.

My process so far looks like this:

1. Copied into my *build/node_modules* folder:

   - core-js/client/shim.min.js
   - zone.js/dist/zone.js
   - reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
   - systemjs/dist/system.src.js
2. Map */scripts* URLs to *node_modules* folder in ExpressJS
3. On my index page, source the above libraries in script tags and load SystemJS:

   ```
   System.config({
       packages: {
           app: {
               defaultExtension: 'js'
           },
           rxjs: {
               defaultExtension: 'js'
           }
       },
       map: {
           'rxjs': '/scripts/rxjs',
           '@angular': '/scripts/@angular'
       }
   })

   System.import('/app/bootstrap')
           .then(null, console.error.bind(console))
   ```
4. And finally, my *bootstrap.ts* file:

   ```
   import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
   import { Component } from '@angular/core'
   @Component({
       selector: 'testing-ang2',
       template: '<span>WIP</span>'
   })
   export class Ang2TestComponent {}

   bootstrap(Ang2TestComponent)
   ```

---

However, when I run this, I get the following errors:

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/scripts/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/ 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:323 Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/scripts/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/scripts/@angular/core/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried copying the *@angular* library into my *build/node_modules* and adding the *index.js* file from each of the folders listed into `<script>` tags on my main page, but that doesn't make any difference.

---

Could anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: Use static in ExpressJS: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: In any particular fashion? I have some static routes set (eg. `app.use('/scripts', express.static('./node_modules/'))`), but I was hoping to avoid a static route attached to the root "/"

Comment: I tried adding that, but the same issue occurs (using */scripts* or not makes no difference). Zone.js is trying to load something there and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

There was two major issues with the configuration above: most of the @angular libraries weren't copied across and SystemJS didn't know how to find them.

To fix the first, copy the entire @angular and rxjs directories into the build/node_modules directory.

For the second, SystemJS needs to be configured like so:

> From [an issue opened for Angular2](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9171#issuecomment-225627581) on github:
>
> ```
> var map = {
>     '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
>     'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
>     'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
>   };
>   // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
>   var packages = {
>     'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
>     'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
>     'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
>   };
>   var ngPackageNames = [ // <-----
>     'common',
>     'compiler',
>     'core',
>     'http',
>     'platform-browser',
>     'platform-browser-dynamic',
>     'router',
>     'router-deprecated',
>     'upgrade',
>   ];
>   // Individual files (~300 requests):
>   function packIndex(pkgName) {
>     packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
>   }
>   // Add package entries for angular packages
>   ngPackageNames.forEach(packIndex);
>   var config = {
>     map: map,
>     packages: packages
>   }
>   System.config(config);`
> ```